# In the proof below doesn't defining $S$, reduces the application of that result to maps of the form of S? if not, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

### Problem from Linear Algebra done right by Sheldon Alxer.

Suppose V is finite-dimensional and $T \in \mathcal L(V)$. Prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of $I \in \mathcal L(V)$ iff $ST = TS$ for every $S \in \mathcal L(V)$.

### Solution from solution manual.

...

(Omitted the forward proof, it's quite straight forward)

To prove in the reverse direction. Suppose $ST = TS$ for all $S \in \mathcal L(V)$. We begin by showing that $(v, Tv)$ is linear dependent for every $v \in  V$. To do this, we fix $v \in  V$ and suppose that $(v, Tv)$ is linearly independent. Then $(v, Tv)$ can be extended to a basis $(v, Tv, u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)$ of $V$.

***This is where I have a problem with***

Define $S \in \mathcal L(V)$ by

**$S(av+ bTv+ u_1+ ...+u_n) = bv$**

Thus $S(Tv) = v$ and $Sv = 0$ and the equation $S(Tv)=T(Sv)$ reduces to $v=0$ which is a contradiction to $(v, Tv)$ being linearly dependent thus they must linearly dependent.

...

(Omitted some other parts)

Comment: What do you have a problem with? I don't understand. We take an arbitrary value of $v$, then we construct some linear mapping $S$ and conclude that $v$ and $Tv$ must be linearly dependent.

Comment: This is a proof of the reverse direction, so we now start from the assumption that $ST = TS$ for all $S$. Hence it has to hold for the $S$ given in the proof as well.

Comment: I want to understand why defining $S$ as above doesn't restrict the statement to hold for only maps in the form of $S$? We have shown that the statement is valid for $S$ as defined in the solution, but the problem ask us to show for an arbitrary $S\in\mathcal L(V)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the principle of linear extension, you can extend any map defined on a basis of $V$, uniquely to a linear map defined on the whole of $V$. This is done as follows: If $B = \{b_i : i \in I\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $f \colon B \to V$ is any map, we extend $f$ by the following: For $v \in V$, we can write $v$ uniquely(!) as a linear combination $v = \sum_i \lambda_i b_i$ now let $$ f(v) = \sum_i \lambda_i f(b_i) $$
This defines $f$ as a linear map $f \colon V \to V$.

This is done above, we define $S$ on the basis $(v, Tv, u_1, \ldots, u_n)$ (note that we can extend every linear independent set to a basis) by setting:
$$ Sv := 0, S(Tv) := v, S(u_i) =0, \qquad i = 1,\ldots, n $$
Then $S$ is a linear map, hence, by assumption on $T$, we have $ST = TS$. Hence,
$$ v = S(Tv) = (ST)v = (TS)v = T(Sv) = T0  =0 $$
This contradicts the linear independence of $(v,Tv)$ (every set containing zero is linear independent).

Comment: Thanks, but I  actually understand every part of the proof apart from where we had to define $S$(you called it 'setting' $S$ in your answer). Doesn't defining S as above restrict the statement to hold for only map in the form of $S$? We have shown that the statement is valid for $S$ as defined in the solution, but the problem ask us to show for an arbitrary $S \in \mathcal L(V)$.

Comment: You are looking at the other direction! You suppose, that the commutativity holds for *every* $S \in L(V)$ and **apply** it for the special $S$ above ...

Comment: Please pardon me. This is the first maths course I'm taking  with this level of rigor. I don't still understand ... logically we have shown it for a special $S$, what about all the other $S \in \mathcal L(V)$? How do we know they give the same conclusion?